# Sort List<String[]>

Tags: c#

How do you sort a List alphanumerically by the value in string[0]?

Comment: @jball: It's not the first character. Each element is an array of strings and he is sorting by the first element of those arrays. Imagine, for example, the index of a book. Each line could be a `string[]` where the first element indicates the word being indexed and the remaining elements are the page numbers. Here it would make sense to sort by the first element.

Comment: take a look at this link [here](http://dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting) they have a very good example of the IComparer interface.
you can use this do create your own Comparer and run your list through it.

Comment: @Jason, ah misread it. I'm on my game today...

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain: I'm with @Jason.

Comment: Example here: http://dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
list.Sort((s, t) => String.Compare(s[0], t[0]));
```

This will sort lexicographically by the first element of each array in `list`.

Since I don't know exactly what you mean by "alphanumerically", if you need a custom string comparing routing, you should do this:

```
class MyStringComparer : IComparer<string> {
    public int Compare(string s, string t) {
        // details elided
    }
}
```

and then

```
var comparer = new MyStringComparer();
list.Sort((s, t) => comparer.Compare(s[0], t[0]));
```

Comment: If the strings in the array could be null, your solution might be better suited for string.Compare(s[0], t[0])

Comment: how would this solve the alphanumerical requirement? W/o a custom comparer, wouldn't this be wrong for "50A" and "100A" ?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Note that I made a remark about custom comparison exactly because I don't know what he means by "alphanumerically."

Comment: yea I wrote the comment before you updated your answer with the custom comparer

Comment: for what it's worth there's an article here showing implementation of an alphanumeric IComparer that might apply here: http://dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting

Comment: @Downvoter: You should really explain why you downvoted here.

Answer (score -1):

This is a terribly oversimplified/pseudo code example... Really stretching here...

```
MyclassZeroIndexComparer : IComparable, IList(Of String[])
{
  private List<String[]> listOfStringArrays;

  //expose this as a public member somewhere...
  private List<String[]> listofStringArrayZeroIndex; 

  //internally store a list of only the first item you want to index....
  //implement your own, add,remove,clear

  void Add(foo item)
  {
    listofStringArrays.Add(Item);
    listofStringArrayZeroIndex.add(item[0]); 
  }

  // continue implementing other methods in the same manner.
}
```