# sort list(of string()) using a variable index into string() as key - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I have a `List(of String())`. I have written a custom comparer (`implements IComparer(of string)`) to do an alphanumeric sort.

Is there a way to sort the List using a given index to determine which position in the `String()` to sort by? In other words one time I might sort by `Index = 0` and another time by `Index = 3`. The length of all `String()` in the list is the same.

For reference this question is similar to [Sort List<String[]>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751866/sort-liststring) except I am using VB.net and that question is hardwired to `Index=0`.

---

**EDIT from OP's comments:**

I started simple with the non custom comparer but I am getting an error: expression does not produce a value. Not sure what I am doing wrong. 
Here is the code:

```
Public Shared Function SortListOfStringArray(ByVal ListOfStringArray As List(Of String()), ByVal SortByIndex As Integer) As List(Of String())
    Return ListOfStringArray.Sort(Function(x, y) x(SortByIndex).CompareTo(y(SortByIndex)))
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort a list of string arrays on a specific index in the array, you use:

```
Dim index As Integer = 1
list.Sort(Function(x, y) x(index).CompareTo(y(index)))
```

Using a custom comparer that would be:

```
Dim index As Integer = 1
list.Sort(Function(x, y) comparer.Compare(x(index), y(index)))
```

Comment: I started simple with the non custom comparer but I am getting an error: expression does not produce a value. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is the code:
Public Shared Function SortListOfStringArray(ByVal ListOfStringArray As List(Of String()), ByVal SortByIndex As Integer) As List(Of String())
Return ListOfStringArray.Sort(Function(x, y) x(SortByIndex).CompareTo(y(SortByIndex)))
End Function

Comment: Sorry for the mess. I have no idea how to get a code block so the code looks clean. I'm relatively new to programming and first time posting to this site.

Comment: @tullynyguy: The `Sort` method doesn't return anything. First sort the list, then return it. If you want to keep the original list and return a new list, you have to copy the list before sorting it.